# Não consigo criar um cliente novo no servidor

Tags: javascript, ajax

Boa noite, sou estudante de JS, html. Estou tentando aprender como posso fazer uma inclusão no servidor ( peço desculpas se descrever com a palavra ou termo incorreto alguma etapa). Eu tenho que criar um site para fazer um CRUD no servidor. Tenho que implementar pelo JAVA SCRIPT o Update,Create,Delete,Read.
No entanto, eu já fiz o READ e DELETE. Estou tentando fazer o CREATE. Mas acho que não sei algum conteúdo. Já pesquisei bastante e eu não consigo incluir nada no Servidor.

Vou mandar a baixo o meu código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<body>
<h2>Tabela De Clientes</h2>
<form id="formularioId">
Nome do cliente:<input type="text" id="form">
uf: <input type="text" id="form" >
Renda Mensal: <input type="text" id="form" >
<button type="submit" id="criarId">Criar</button>
</form>
<br><br> <button type="button" id=tabela>Tabela</button>  
<br><br>
Resultado:<br>
<p id="listaCliente" ></p>
<script>
var url="httpEndereço";
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#tabela").click(function(){
$.get("https://clienteweb2017.000webhostapp.com/crud_ajax_json/
getDadosClientes.php")
    .done(function(data,status){
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(obj);
        montarTabela(obj);
        })

    .fail(function(){
    alert("Problema de conexão");
    });


    });
 function montarTabela(obj){
  var i;

  //console.log (response.responseXML);

  //var xmlDoc = response.responseXML;  

  var table="<table border=1  style=border-collapse:'collapse';><tr> 
  <th>Id</th><th>Nome</th><th>uf</th><th>Renda Mensal</th><th>remover</th> 
  </tr>";

  //var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ALBUM");

   for (n of obj.data) { 
   table += "<tr><td>" + n.id +"</td><td>" +n.nome +
   "</td><td>" + n.uf +"</td><td>" + n.rendamensal+"</td><td><a 
    href='#'class='excluir'>remover</a></td></tr>";
   }
   $("#listaCliente").html(table);
   }
    $("body").on("click", ".excluir",function(){

    var Cid=$(this).parent().siblings(0).html();


   $.get("https://clienteweb2017.000webhostapp.com/crud_ajax_json/
   deleteCliente.php?id="+Cid)
    .done(function(){
        //alert("Removido!!!");
        })

    .fail(function(){
    alert("Problema de conexão");
    });
    });
    });//Fim da Ready
    var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    $(document).ready(function(){

     $("body").on("click", "#criarId",function(){

    var criacao=$('#formularioId');
    $.get("https://clienteweb2017.000webhostapp.com/crud_ajax_json/
    createCliente.php?nome="+criacao)
      .done(function(){
         //alert("Removido!!!");
            })

      .fail(function(){
       alert("Problema de conexão");
       });
        xhttp.send();
       });
        });//Fim da Ready
   </script>
   </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como é a estrutura da tabela de users? E ajudava tb ver o createCliente.php.
Quando trabalhar por AJAX, convém estar sempre atento à aba Rede (Network) da consola do browser, seja como for, está, pelos vistos, a enviar o formulário e não apenas o valor do input 'nome'. Mais ainda, todos os campos do formulário tem o mesmo id e não deveria.

```
<form id="formularioId">
Nome do cliente:<input type="text" **id="form"**>
uf: <input type="text" **id="form"** >
Renda Mensal: <input type="text" **id="form"** >
<button type="submit" id="criarId">Criar</button>
</form>
```

Deveria ser, por exemplo:

```
<form id="formularioId">
Nome do cliente:<input type="text" id="nomeCliente">
uf: <input type="text" id="ufCliente" >
Renda Mensal: <input type="text" id="rendaCliente" >
<button type="submit" id="criarId">Criar</button>
</form>
```

Assim, via javascript:

```
var criacao=$('#nomeCliente').val();
    $.get("https://clienteweb2017.000webhostapp.com/crud_ajax_json/
    createCliente.php?nome="+criacao)
      .done(function(){
         //alert("Removido!!!");
            })

      .fail(function(){
       alert("Problema de conexão");
       });
        xhttp.send();
});
```

Por fim, tem de usar GET para realizar os pedidos? POST seria muito melhor - razoavelmente mais seguro.

Comment: 1-Ainda não estudei sobre "POST" em XMLHttpRequest. Por isso que tenho que fazer pelo "GET".
2- Esse tópico do "id" Ajudou muito. Obrigado.

Por fim, gostaria de entender uma coisa. Com essa linha:

var criacao=$('#nomeCliente').val();

Eu Consigo pegar os dados do POST corretamente?

Comment: Neste caso, só vai buscar o valor do campo do nome do cliente, para ir buscar a info toda: var criacao=$('#nomeCliente').val(); var ud=$('#ufCliente').val(); e var renda=$('#rendaCliente').val();

Comment: É porque ele continua falhando. Ele entra no ".fail()" e abre o alert que deixei lá.

Comment: Isso pode ser outra coisa... Coloque response a ser passada na função done, tipo .done(function(response){ console.log(response);}). fail bla bla bla, e veja o que o browser cospe na consola e na aba Network ou Rede...

Comment: Não teve nenhum resultado no console.

Comment: E na aba Rede? Filtre por pedidos XHR. Pode não encontrar o URL do pedido, pode o ficheiro até estar com o nome diferente de createCliente, pode o upload ter corrido mal e o ficheiro incompleto, etc... Pode ser erro no PHP ou na própria query de inserção... Qualquer coisa, poste aqui o código php do createCliente.php

Comment: Agora estou conseguindo incluir mas estou com problemas pois continua dando um problema de conexao. Tem algo que eu devo procurar ? Tipo eu olhei no rede(network) como pediu, olhei no console e o erro não está aparecendo! Desculpa mas sou iniciante e por isso estou com tantas dúvidas.

Comment: Na boa, acontece até a pros, por isso não se preocupe :) não dispara erro nenhum na consola, nem de jquery? E se em vez de $("body").on("click", "#criarId",function(){ for só $("#criarId").on("click", function(){ ??

Comment: Consegui ajeitar o código neste meio tempo. Agora está inserindo, removendo e mostrando. Estou tentando estudar como posso editar ou atualizar os regissstros. Se quiser posso postar o código atual aqui pra você ver.

Comment: Boa! Se está a funcionar não precisa postar o código. A mecânica de editar vai dar mais trabalho e vai exigir mais atenção. Bom trabalho e boa sorte :)